Defining the cause of handshake failure
I'm trying to make an LDAP connection between a Spring boot application and an external LDAP server. The spring boot app is running on a linux server. The problem is that I always have a handshake failure.
I correctly verified that the connection to the LDAP server was working, and it is. I am able to do an ldapsearch and fetch data. The connection is done on port 636 because it only accepts ldaps.
Here is what I tried to solve this problem :

I correctly defined ciphers in my spring boot configuration file (server.ssl.ciphers). I set everyone that are accepted to the LDAP server (I used nmap to know which ciphers was okay).
I also check for truststore and keystore. I have every certificates that are trusted by the server. I correctly set them in the configuration file. I saw that when certificate is bad there is a specific type of error message that can give a hint on the problem, but as i said before i only have a "Handshake failure" that don't give me more information.
The current TLS protocol used is the same used for ldapsearch so it should not be a problem.

I used tcpdump to capture packets and I compared the communication of the ldapsearch and of my connection from my spring boot app. I noticed that even if the desired connections are pointing on the same ip, my ldapsearch is not communicating with the ip I set but another one and so I think there is probably a proxy that may redirect the request automatically but I'm absolutely not sure.
When looking packets of the spring boot app connection, I only see a ClientHello and the ACK of the LDAP server, and after I see an other packet that contain the alert "Handshake failure" and nothing else.
Do you think the problem could came from a proxy or firewall that block the spring boot app connections but not ldapsearch command, and do you know if I could have more information about the handshake failure (but I don't have access to the LDAP server...).

I've voted to close this as I don't see anything about actual SW development, but I'll leave you with a hint: the server is also validated by name in the certificate, and you're talking about IP based access. Also Java has debug settings for their TLS provider which should allow you to get more specific information about the failure (assuming you don't use a TLS-accelerator or proxy of course).
